# Unable to generate allure report using testng and maven

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml, allure

#### TestNG Version

7.1.0

#### Expected behavior

mvn test command should execute the test normally, knowing that same POM was working fine before until I update testNG and some other dependencies, I'm using allure with testNG and maven as well, now if I disabled allure-TestNG test will be executed but allure won't generate any report

#### Actual behavior

I'm getting this error 
      Please refer to C:\Users\warrior\Desktop\MobileAutomationTest\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
There was an error in the forked processorg/testng/IInvokedMethodListener2
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked processorg/testng/IInvokedMethodL
istener2

#### Is the issue reproducible on a runner?

- [x] Maven
- [x] IntelliJ

#### Test case sample

POM file

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
   4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MobileAutomationTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>SafeApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <jre.level>1.8</jre.level>
        <jdk.level>1.8</jdk.level>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler plug-in -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.level}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.level}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Added Surefire Plugin configuration to execute tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/TestNG.xml/</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng &ndash;&gt;-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                <version>7.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
                <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
                <version>2.41.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- log4j2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.29</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <reporting>
            <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportDirectory>${basedir}\target\allure-report</reportDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>

    </project>
```

Comment: Hey your Test case sample works ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with Allure reports which is NOT compatible with TestNG `7.1.0`.

TestNG `7.1.0` removed the listener `IInvokedMethodListener2` interface.

This needs to be fixed in Allure reports.

I have also added more information in the github issue that was logged for this : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2246

Comment: you thats true i have downgraded testng version to 7.0.0 and its working

Comment: @AmrKamel - Can you please accept my answer so that the question gets closed ?

Comment: Done thx, sorry was waiting just in case someone encountered the same issue and find away around

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me also and it resolved via downgrading test-ng version to 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on your project folder path in your terminal

`mvn io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:serve`